# jquery, jquery mobile Browser Back button issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, browser, mobile, back

Here is an automatic page transtion issue I've with my jquery mobile page. Any help is appreciated please.

I am on page A, I click on a link, then I go to page "B". Now I click on a link in Page "B" to go to Page C.

On Page C I click browser back button (iphone at the bottom left) it takes me to page B as desired good. Now, I click on the same link to go back to Page C. This time, the browser flashes the Page "C" however, soon automatically (with the jquery mobile loading image in the middle it does a transition slide) it loads Page "B" instead. When I look at the URL on the top, I still pageC.html url and not B. only the content is of Page B.

Do I make sense? What is happening? Help me please.

More info: what am I using?

Thanks much

Comment: Can you please post your code snipe so that i can have a better look.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I'm not able to get exact issue with your code. Please take a look at online documentation, may be can help you. http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you/

Comment: you can edit your question and can put your code in codeblock

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it by setting hashListeningEnabled to false.

```
$.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled      : false,
    hashListeningEnabled: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled      : false,
    hashListeningEnabled: false
});

this also worked for me. On iPhone 5s, I would browse to a page (using the .pagecontainer("change") method). The page was dynamically generated in client code, so it wasn't an actual URL. Anyway, the first time I used the back button, it would work. The second time I navigated to a different page, the transition would happen, and then the page would do a quick flash/reload. After that, the back button stopped working.

Implementing this code in the  tag worked for me. MAKE SURE you put this AFTER your jquery reference, but BEFORE your jquery MOBILE reference. This is a really frustrating Gotcha. My  tag looks like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="phonebook.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,

I guess Issue is with your file structure.
You are using jquery mobile library but at the same time you are working with two pages to have transitions which won't work.

Comment: Also check your Email, I have sent you demo package for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: Working with multiple pages is inevitable. Single page solution works only to an extent as long as u r not dealing with too much of backend stuff. Also, stuffing everything in a single page will also increase the size of mobile page.  <br/>


It seems like this browser back button issue is always there. As I see a same kind of issue exists on the jquerymobile.com pages as well.  <br/>  <br/>

Here is another link that outlines the issue on jquerymobile.com page. Sounds very similar.


http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-true-browser-back-button-issue

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue.  Adding `data-ajax="false"` to the link sometimes helps.

For example change

```
`<a href="#" data-role="button" id="fix_link">Another Page</a>`
```

TO

```
`<a data-ajax="false" href="#" data-role="button" id="fix_link">Another Page</a>`
```

There are many places to read about how JQuery Mobile loads pages and works with navigation but I learned the most by tinkering around with this and sometimes `data-rel="external"` is certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AJAX navigation (i.e. you have the option `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled` set to false), JQuery Mobile recommends to also disable `$.mobile.pushStateEnabled` to fix those browser issues:

> Note: When building a jQuery Mobile application where the Ajax navigation system is disabled globally or frequently disabled on individual links, we recommend disabling the $.mobile.pushStateEnabled global configuration option to avoid inconsistent navigation behavior in some browsers.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/navigation-linking-pages/

To disable it:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```